# What is the ModuleRefCollection for in a BizTalk bindings file?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

What is the ModuleRefCollection, and child ModuleRef, Services and TrackedSchema for in a BizTalk binding file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ModuleRefCollection is the container for the Schemas (TrackedSchemas) and Orchestrations (Services) associated with the Application.  A Module being an Assembly for Orchestrations and the special Application ModuleRef for TrackedSchemas.

Note, TrackedSchemas is a slight misnomer.  It contains the configuration for all Deployed Schemas, not just tracked Schemas.

Each element contains all the binding information, what you configure in BizTalk Administrator, for it's respective artifact.

So, a Schema element will list all the Properties you have checked on it's Tracking Tab.

A Service element will have all of the Port and Host Bindings for that Orchestration.

It's pretty easy to interpret yourself.  Take any Application you have that has one or more Orchestrations and export the Bindings.  You'll see everything you've configured in BT Admin reflected there.